# How can i reach sublass from parentclass? (in java)

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I have 5 different class. These are ASeat, BSeat, CSeat, Seat, Appointment. ASeat, BSeat, CSeat is inheriting the Seat class. Appointment class determines which class to choose(ASeat,BSeat,CSeat). Lets say if value(jobType) equals 1 we will get ASeat as parameter, if it equals 2 BSeat as parameter and if it equals 3 we will get CSeat as parameter.

I've tried code like below but It didn't work

How can I do that?

Sample code from Appointment class(Constructor):

```
public Appointment(jobType,Seat seat) {
   if(jobtype==1){
       seat.ASeat.function1();
      }
}
```

I want to define class by a jobType
I've written a few examples to better understand below

```
public Appointment(1,ASeat aseat) {
   
       ASeat.function1();
      
}
```

---

```
public Appointment(2,BSeat bseat) {
   
       bseat.function2();
      
}
```

---

```
public Appointment(3,CSeat cseat) {
   
       cseat.function3();
      
}
```

If i use like below. it would so unnecesary and gibbish

```
public Appointment(Dentist dentist, Patient patient,int jobType,ASeat aseat,BSeat bseat,CSeat cseat) {
if(jobType==1){
            aseat.function1();
}
if(jobType==2){
            bseat.function2();
}
if(jobType==3){
            cseat.function3();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you want to use the FactoryPattern.

A clear example is defined here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: Links may not work at some point. It is encouraged to not just only post a link but also provide some explaination.

Comment: @dan1st  you are right, but I feel bad to copy someones work and paste it in stackoverlfow...that is why I pointed to it.

Comment: You can summarize what your article is about and include the link.

Comment: I will try to get better at this @dan1st thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, all subclasses have a method with the same signature and you want to call that method.

If you want to call it, you need to extract it in the superclass and override it:

```java
public class Seat{
    public void function(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException ("Not implemented for superclass");
    }
}

public class ASeat extends Seat{
    @Override
    public void function(){
        //Your code
    }
}
//where you call it
seat.function();
```

If the superclass is abstract, you could even use an abstract method:

```java
public abstract class Seat{
    public abstract void function();
}

public class ASeat extends Seat{
    @Override
    public void function(){
        //Your code
    }
}
//where you call it
seat.function();
```

Comment: Actually all subclasses have a different method, thats why i asked the question. I've rewritten the question to not misunderstand

Comment: @0xtagh But why not call them the same method as in this answer. This is one of the strengths of OOP.

Comment: Because function1,function2,function3 completely different methods its just example

Comment: It depends. Are those methods there for doing the same thing, just for different seats? The best solution for this problem depends on the exact problem.